# QT installer worked coding not give result

Tags: c++, qt

I download the app [wifimouse](https://wifimouse.github.io/) for windows.

[wifimouse](https://wifimouse.github.io/) app fully build with qt.

[Source code of wifimouse server application](https://github.com/krogank9/WifiMouseServer)

I install and run wifimouse app in my computer it works perfectly and all the options are works smoothly.

But, If I run the same code in my computer it not works properly.

For example ; In wifimouse application there is an option for brightness controling

[Brightness code](https://github.com/krogank9/WifiMouseServer/blob/master/fakeinput-windows.cpp#L267)

[image]

error comes like this. But , it works smoothly in downloaded [installer from here](https://wifimouse.github.io/)

Problem with qt in getting outputs.

[My project](https://github.com/krogank9/WifiMouseServer)

I want to get the cpu usage , ram usage ,process list and app list with qt.

**In Windows**

[image: windows os]

I am getting ram usage from this [code](https://github.com/krogank9/WifiMouseServer/blob/master/fakeinput-windows.cpp#L410).

But [app list](https://github.com/krogank9/WifiMouseServer/blob/master/fakeinput-windows.cpp#L370) , [cpu usage](https://github.com/krogank9/WifiMouseServer/blob/master/fakeinput-windows.cpp#L402) and [process](https://github.com/krogank9/WifiMouseServer/blob/master/fakeinput-windows.cpp#L434) outputs are not showed.

**In linux**

[image]

In linux the [cpu usage](https://github.com/krogank9/WifiMouseServer/blob/master/fakeinput-linux.cpp#L283) output not showed.

**In Mac**

[image]

In mac the [app list](https://github.com/krogank9/WifiMouseServer/blob/master/fakeinput-mac.cpp#L305) output not showed.

Why this problem occured ?